# Hover doesn't work on CSS, even in simple test code

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, event-handling, hover

I can't get the hover function to work even in a simple test code. Its driving me crazy. this code just try to change the background code of a

when hovering over a button. what am I missing?

```
<!doctype html>

<button id="dropdownmenu"></button>
<p id="test"> this is a test <p>

<style>
#test{
  background-color: red;
}
#dropdownmenu{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
#dropdownmenu: hover #test{
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible answers for your question:

1. I'm not 100% sure if the `<p>` is supposed to be inside or outside the `<button>`... one of the answers would be to move the `<p>` inside the button, like:

```
<button id="dropdownmenu">
    <p id="test"> this is a test <p>
</button>
```

2. Now, if you want to to have the `<p>` outside the `<button>` you could simply add a + after the hover, like:

```
#dropdownmenu:hover + #test{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the whitespace between the `:` and `hover`. Hover is a pseudoselector and you should obbey the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You have two cards, it's not related. If you want to change background color of `<p>` you can use JavaScript for do this.

```html
<button onmouseover="changeColor()"  id="dropdownmenu">hover</button>
<p id="test"> this is a test <p>
<script>    

function changeColor() {
    let text = document.getElementById("test");
    text.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
}
</script>

<style>
#test{
  background-color: red;
}
#dropdownmenu{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
</style>

</html>
```