# When I hover over a button, it does not highlight

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a button highlight when I hover over it, but it doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing something wrong? It seems to work on the dropdown menu I made, but not the buttons. I am new to html and css and I couldn't seem to find an answer anywhere online.

```css
/*a button that when clicked on, sends to a page about me*/
  .SiteMakerButton {
    padding : 16px;
    width: 15%%;
    text-align : left;
    background-color: rgb(37, 217, 184);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
  }



  /*a button that takes you to the main paige*/
  .HomeButton {
    padding : 16px;
    width: 15%%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgb(37, 217, 184);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
  }
  

  .HomeButton :hover {background-color: white; color: black;}

  .SiteMakerButton :hover {background-color: white; color: black;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>TESTING</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class = TopBannerDiv>
    <button class = "HomeButton">Home</button>
    <button class = "SiteMakerButton">About The Site Maker</button>
    <div class = "dropdown">
      <button class = "dropbtn">Units</button>
      <div class = "dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Unit 1</a>
        <a href="#">Unit 2</a>
        <a href="#">Unit 3</a>
        <a href="#">Unit 4</a>
        <a href="#">Unit 5</a>
        <a href="#">Unit 6</a>
        <a href="#">Unit 7</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge.js" 
theme="blue" defer></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you add your html too please?

Comment: The purpose of snippets is to demonstrate  the issue you are having when you click "Run code snippet" Then answerers can click "Copy snippet to answer", edit their copy, and tell you what they did and why. Right now, nothing interesting happens because the CSS code is in the HTML box, and there's no HTML for it to style. Please [edit] your question to make that work.

Comment: In this case, we can tell that you've put a space between the class selector (`.HomeButton`) and the `:hover` pseudo-class, which means it looks for separate descendant elements within the button for the `:hover` to occur on. A common beginner's mistake, and one which does not need answers.

Comment: Also, duplicate of [Hover doesn't work on CSS, even in simple test code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69139374/215552)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing

```
.HomeButton:hover {background-color: white; color: black;}
```

like this, there is a difference in CSS between having spaces and not.

Also, use inspect element to make sure that there is nothing that is overwriting your style.

Answer (score -1):

Reduce the space between the class and the pesudo class (means hover)

```
.HomeButton:hover {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black;
}

.SiteMakerButton:hover {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black;
}
```